Reference request on Georg Cantor
Georg Cantor is reported to have stated "Das Wesen der Mathematik liegt in ihrer Freiheit." Where did he state this, if at all?

Georg Cantor, "Ueber unendliche, lineare Punktmannichfaltigkeiten. 5. Fortsetzung." Mathematische Annalen, Vol. 21, No. 4, 1883, pp. 545-591. On p. 564:

Dagegen scheint mir aber jede überflüssige Einengung des mathematischen Forschungstriebes eine viel grössere Gefahr mit sich zu bringen und eine um so grössere, als dafür aus dem Wesen der Wissenschaft wirklich keinerlei Rechtfertigung gezogen werden kann; denn das Wesen der Mathematik liegt gerade in ihrer Freiheit.

Manually reviewed Google translation:
"On the other hand, it seems to me that any unnecessary restriction of the drive for mathematical research brings with it a much greater danger, and an even greater one because no justification for it can really be drawn from the nature of science; for the nature of mathematics lies precisely in its freedom."

Compare also: Cantor, G. (1883). Grundlagen einer allgemeinen Mannichfaltigkeitslehre: ein mathematisch-philosophischer Versuch in der Lehre des Unendlichen. Teubner. p. 20. last sentence of first paragraph.

@GeorgEssl Cantor must have been satisfied with the sentence, as he reused it. :)
